# How to call a multidimensional polyhedron

Tags: geometry, terminology

A polygon is a 2-D shape with a finite number of straight sides. A polyhedron is a 3-D shape with flat polygonal faces.

I want to talk about multidimensional "polyhedrons" of an arbitrary dimension, i.e a hyperdimensional shape whose "sides" are multidimensional "polyhedrons" of a dimension lower by 1.

What is the proper name when talking about such geometries, is hyper polyhedrons (as in hypercubes) appropriate or is there another name.

Answer (score 4):

The word you want is "[polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope)".